FlowRow make elements in row stretch to available width
In Jetpack Compose FlowRow, how can I make the elements within the rows stretch the full width of the screen.
If this code is run on a Pixel 8, the first 4 names are on one row which is what I want, but there is white space after the last name (Peter).  I basically want the view to dynamically add even spacing around all 4 pieces of text so that the full view width is used.
The 1st image shows what the code is currently doing.  The 2nd image shows what I want the code to do (I have manually created this view by specifying the padding for each element in nameOptions), but want a way for it to be done automatically based on the available width
[

@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun Names() {

    var nameOptions = arrayOf("Luke", "Christopher", "Samuel", "Peter", "Johnathan", "James", "Aydan", "Matthew", "Andrew")


    Column (
        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
    ) {

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
        
        FlowRow(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        ) {

            for (name in nameOptions) {

                Text(
                    text = name,
                    softWrap = false,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .border(
                            width = 1.dp,
                            color = Color.Black,
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)
                        )
                        .padding(10.dp)
                )
            }
        }

    }

}


I don't think that's possible with FlowRow because you only want to add the additional padding to the first two rows, not the last. Although you can add an evenly distributed space between the Texts (not padding, i.e. you have additional space outside the Text) by using horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween, an Arrangement in general also cannot differentiate between the first two rows and the last row. I don't see how this last row semantic can be easily implemented.

There is also a (rejected) feature request to extend Arrangements to differentiate the last row from the rest: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/269032073

Thanks for the info @Leviathan.  I'm fine with the last row also extending to the full screen width.  Is there a solution you know of for this using padding inside the text bubble instead of spacing outside the text bubble.

You could use a custom Layout. Following I tested and it seemed to work quite well:

@Composable
fun Names() {
    var nameOptions = arrayOf(
        "Luke",
        "Christopher",
        "Samuel",
        "Peter",
        "Johnathan",
        "James",
        "Aydan",
        "Matthew",
        "Andrew"
    )
    
    
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
    ) {
    
        val horizontalItemSpacing = with(LocalDensity.current) { 10.dp.roundToPx() }
        val verticalItemSpacing = with(LocalDensity.current) { 10.dp.roundToPx() }
    
        Layout(
            content = {
                for (name in nameOptions) {
    
                    Text(
                        text = name,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .border(
                                width = 1.dp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp)
                            )
                            .padding(10.dp),
                        // Because default is left aligned
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        softWrap = false,
                    )
                }
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        ) { measurables, constraints ->
            if (measurables.isEmpty()) return@Layout layout(0, 0) { }

            // Firstly get the widths of the elements
            val widths = measurables.map { it.minIntrinsicWidth(Int.MAX_VALUE) }

            // Fit them in the rows
            val fittingWidths = mutableListOf(mutableListOf<Int>()).apply {
                // Overflow in next row
                var currentRow = first()
                for (width in widths) {
                    val availableWidth =
                        constraints.maxWidth - currentRow.sum() - currentRow.size * horizontalItemSpacing
                    if (width > availableWidth && currentRow.isNotEmpty())
                        currentRow = mutableListOf<Int>().also(::add)
                    currentRow.add(width.coerceAtMost(constraints.maxWidth))
                }
            }
    
            val layoutWidth = max(
                constraints.minWidth,
                fittingWidths.maxOf { row ->
                    row.sum() + (row.size - 1) * horizontalItemSpacing
                },
            )
    
            // Distribute remaining space
            for (row in fittingWidths) {
                val distributeWidth =
                    (layoutWidth - (row.sum() + (row.size - 1) * horizontalItemSpacing)) / row.size
                row.replaceAll { width -> width + distributeWidth }
            }
    
            var i = 0
            val placeables = fittingWidths
                .dropLast(1).map { row ->
                    row.map { width ->
                        measurables[i++].measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = width))
                    }
                }
                // Last row
                .plusElement(fittingWidths.last().map {
                    measurables[i++].measure(constraints.copy(minWidth = 0))
                })
    
            val layoutHeight = placeables.sumOf { row ->
                row.maxOf { placeable -> placeable.height }
            } + (placeables.size - 1) * verticalItemSpacing
    
            layout(width = layoutWidth, height = layoutHeight) {
                var posX = 0
                var posY = 0
    
                for (row in placeables) {
                    val rowHeight = row.maxOf { placeable ->
                        placeable.placeRelative(posX, posY)
    
                        posX += placeable.width + horizontalItemSpacing
                        placeable.height
                    }
    
                    posX = 0
                    posY += rowHeight + verticalItemSpacing
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Note that the text has to be manually center aligned.
I'd suggest you to put the layout in a separate composable with horizontal and vertical item spacing as parameters together with modifier and content that you can apply to the Layout.
edit: Added a check at the top of the measure policy to avoid division by zero.

Great implementation, I like it.

Fantastic answer.  Appreciate it!
